# Sequence-to-Sequence models without specifying the start and end of sentences

Tags: deep-learning, sequence-modeling

Is there a seq-to-seq model which does not require to know the start and end of a sentence? I need to model a system which gets a long sequence of words and creates a long sequence of tokens as long as the input. For example it takes a sequence of 1000 words and creates a sequence of 1000 tokens, each token corresponds to an input word.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean a system that **tokenize** a sentence? A system taht does that do that does not need teh start of the sequence and anchor not does it uses a neural network based approach.

Comment: So, isn't there any model that creates a seq-to-seq model without tokenizing?